# Assign an object to 2 parents with offset for each

Tags: constraints

I have a game character who uses a shield. Her armature has 2 bones for the shield: the "stowed" position and the "using" position - i.e.: the shield is stowed on an extended back bone, and is used on an extended hand bone.

I can parent the shield to both bones by using the ChildOf constraint, but it only gives the ability to use the parent's position verbatim. I need to position it at the parent, but with an offset. Like, hand bone but rotated on X by 30, and back bone but rotated X by 15.

Is there any way to do this? Something like a ChildOf-plus-Offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out.

I created an Empty for each target bone, parented each empty to the respective bone, positioned it as desired, then used the empties as targets for the ChildOf constraints.